# Using Axon for CQRS and event sourcing. Aggregate not found in event store

Tags: axon

I am new to Axon and have written a sample code wherein we have an inventory service which is used for adding new inventory, updating inventory and we want to send events to Product Service for any update. Product service should act as a read replica to Inventory Service.

Inventory Service code:

So I created Inventory Aggregate which various command handlers.
[image]

Inventory Controller responsible for sending commands

[image]

In product Service, I added event handlers

[image]

Problem i am facing currently is, when i add a new inventory, it gets reflected in product service db but when i try to do update, it gives me an exception: 
***Command 'com.example.demo.command.UpdateInventoryCommand' resulted in org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandExecutionException(The aggregate was not found in the event store)
org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.command.AxonServerRemoteCommandHandlingException: An exception was thrown by the remote message handling component: The aggregate was not found in the event store***

When i try to make one more insert into inventory, Inventory Service throws Exception saying:

***: "OUT_OF_RANGE: [AXONIQ-2000] Invalid sequence number 0 for aggregate 0, expected 1",  An exception was thrown by the remote message handling component: OUT_OF_RANGE: [AXONIQ-2000] Invalid sequence number 0 for aggregate 0, expected 1 Caused by OUT_OF_RANGE: [AXONIQ-2000] Invalid sequence number 0 for aggregate 0, expected 1***

Any help would be really appreciated.
**Complete code available at :**

https://github.com/jahanvibansal/Axon-ProductService

https://github.com/jahanvibansal/Axon-InventoryOrderService

Comment: I do not think this a code thing @PayalBansal, but more something with how you are running and have configured Axon Server. Please update your ticket with specifics how your project is started, how Axon Server is started and if you're configuring anything specifics for the event storage side of things.

Comment: Yes, I started my axon server before that. But I had not done any configuration for event storage side of things. I realized we need to specify axon.eventhandling.processors.name.mode=tracking property in spring boot application which got it working.  I understand there are 2 modes tracking and publish subscribe. I would read more about it.

Comment: Aaaah missed a little piece of configuration. Great that you've solved it yourself @PayalBansal! Make sure to mark your response as the answer for future answer-seekers :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

. I realized we need to specify axon.eventhandling.processors.name.mode=tracking property in spring boot application which got it working. I understand there are 2 modes tracking and publish subscribe. I would read more about it.